# Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ has prime order . Then precisely when $G$ is isomorphic to $ H × G/H$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$  be a finite group with a normal subgroup $H$  . Then precisely when  $G$  is isomorphic to $ H × G/H$ .

I was trying to directly construct an isomorphism with trial and error between  $G$ and $ H × G/H$ and my hope was to find appropriate conditions on $G$ and $H$ along the way.But so far not able to make any notable progress.

I was trying different onto homomorphisms from $G\to H$ and $G\to G/H$ , and then use these homomorphisms as the first and the second component of the desired isomorphism between $G$ and $ H × G/H$. I was trying to see how those homomorphisms should relate to each other in order to do the job and  what constrain they put on $G$ and $H$ ?

Any progress in this situation will be help full to me .Thanks

Comment: It is not very clear to me, what are you asking. Please give more details.

Comment: This is a very broad question. One characterization is when there is a projection $\pi:G\to H$ which is the identity on $H$.

Comment: A necessary (but not sufficient) condition is that $H$ is in the center of $G$.